# Can't load a local javascript file into the webview

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I have a webview inside a uwp application and i need to inject some javascript files into it. I can't include them in the source code of the html page.

This is what I have so far.

```
private async void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    await Webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[]
    {
        "var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type='text/javascript'; script.charset='UTF-8'; script.src ="
        + "'ms-appx://Apps.Webapp/JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'"
        + ";document.body.appendChild(script);"
    });
}
```

But when i try with the direct invocation the files are simple not loaded

Anyone has any thoughts that can help me?

Edit: I have tried with no luck

```
"'ms-appx-web://Apps.Webapp/JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I got a working solution:

```
private async void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{    
   string scriptToLoad = File.ReadAllText("Apps.Webapp/JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js");
   string[] arguments = { scriptToLoad };
   await WebBrowserWizzio.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", arguments);
}
```

This way i'm injecting the whole script into the page and not only the path.

Answer (score 1):

To load file from the your app package in the `WebView` you need to use  **`ms-appx-web`** scheme, not `ms-appx`. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ms-appx-web:///JS/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

More details please reference the "Navigating to content section" of [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) class.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, even if i put the js in the assets folder of the main application.

Comment: @Lucky, could you please detail  what's the expect results for working? I mean did you have any effects means it worked? This code snippet can load the js file successfully in  html file on my side. Did you have a [mcve] for testing on our side?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Because of the nature of the project i couldn't go to a example. Instead of linking the resource I opted out for loading the whole string.