# MAUI WebView Control and CORS

Tags: webview, maui, mathml

Trying to write a MAUI app using WebView control so I can teach students how to solve complex math problems.  I choose to use MathML since it supports most math symbols to include automatically adjusting their size as needed.  I also use MathML polyfills written by w3c for fix issues.

The app works in Windows, but in Android I get the following error:

[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(641)] "Access to script at '**file:///android_asset/mathml-polyfills-main/all-polyfills.js**' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.", source: **file:///android_asset/mathml-polyfills-main/acid-test.html** (641).

I understand what CORS is but all JavsScript files are in the app.  No external requests.  I searched the web for a way to get around the CORS issue.  I don’t think I want to disable it if there is a way.  A.I. says setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs property was deprecated in API level 30.  Webview.settings and ms-appx-web I believe are a WinUI feature.  A.I. suggested webview.settings but I don’t know where to place this code.  One of the schemes listed was data but that is for embedding files.  To use other schemes a web server is required.  Do I really have to setup a web server on my Android MAUI app and if som how?

What I’ve tried:

[Can't use WebView with local files stored as MauiAssets on Windows · Issue #16646 · dotnet/maui · GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16646)

[Allow local files (PWA app) in WebView (CORS) · Issue #8380 · dotnet/maui · GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8380)

[c# - Can't load a local javascript file into the webview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283617/cant-load-a-local-javascript-file-into-the-webview)

[c# - Can't load a local javascript file into the webview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283617/cant-load-a-local-javascript-file-into-the-webview)

[WebView - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-8.0&pivots=devices-windows)

[javascript - Access to script at "file" from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76906253/access-to-script-at-file-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy)

[From origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests error - JavaScript - The freeCodeCamp Forum](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-cross-origin-requests-error/610295)

Below are links to MathML polyfills and my app posted on GitHub.  My app already contains all the polyfills.  I hope I’m overlooking something stupid although one of the articles I read says this my be a bug.

I did download my source code from GitHub as a customer.  It did compile and ran under Windows.  It compiled under Android but I did get the CORS error.  I'm running VS 2022, Maui 8.

[w3c/mathml-polyfills: Polyfills for MathML features (github.com)](https://github.com/w3c/mathml-polyfills)

[mthanson8333/MathML: Use MathML with MAUI WebView control (github.com)](https://github.com/mthanson8333/MathML)

Comment: Your issue seems Android-specific. And, possibly, from the fact that you're mixing local file references and remote resources. Hence the CORS violation. Perhaps this link may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648616/webview-javascript-cross-domain-from-a-local-html-file. Alternatively, consider moving your local assets online. For example, you can host and serve your files in GitHub Pages.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I looked through the external links and 98% of them are xmlns.  There are some external links which I will correct.  There are some external links inside the Tizen manifest.  Not sure if I can correct them.  I'll let you know if this works.  Don't want to move assets online since this is supposed to be a calculator app.

Comment: I replaced the external links with local ones but still did not work.  I took a second look at the link you provided.  This did give me some additional information.  setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs property has been deprecated since API 30.  Found ConfigureNative method of the WebViewHandler.  In your link it mentioned setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs and WebSettings.  I will continue to look at these but I can't find a website that demonstrates these from beginning.  I'm trying to learn MAUI but getting nowhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I found that I needed to set `AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs` to `true`, but, for good measure, let's set a bunch of these settings via a custom `WebViewHandler` in your `App.xaml.cs` constructor:

```cs
        public App()
        {
            Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                handler.PlatformView.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
#endif
            });

            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1373758/how-can-i-display-a-pdf-file-in-maui
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.webkit.websettings.allowuniversalaccessfromfileurls?view=net-android-34.0

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I implemented the first link with no luck.  I got the following error message: [AndroidProtocolHandler] Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/sayHi.  If I remove the import and export statements, and use script tags to include javascript files the old way, it works.  Type cannot be module.  I get the same error if I remove the implementation.  Not sure if WebView control is ECMAScript 2015 compliant or just doesn't support import export.  I will submit a ticket.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. However, I tested the above with an HTML-jQuery application that sums values from two inputs. The jQuery only started working with the above code. I am not sure if it will help, but, I can share my app here or on GitHub tomorrow.

Comment: I got it to work!!!  The issue is the import statement.  While reviewing import and export statements the import examples were not using the .js file extension.  This was what I was doing.  I added the .js file extension to the import statement and everything worked.  The links you sent also helped a lot; especially the modification to App.xaml.cs file.  Modification to MainPage.xaml.cs not necessary.  I want to thank you again for your help and patience.

Comment: Goods stuff. You should use .gitignore to exclude bin and obj folders from your git repo.

Comment: Sorry I'll try to remember that next time.